# How to get iOS's unique identifier from app?

Tags: iphone

I have checked online that getting IMEI must use private methods and thus violate the agreement and might be rejected. What I need is not the IMEI number, but any unique identifier of the phone, it can be meaning less or do

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] uniqueIdentifier]
```

Answer (score 0):

As of iOS 5.0 this property is deprecated and [Apple advises](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDevice_Class/Reference/UIDevice.html) that you create your own unique app id:

> Do not use the uniqueIdentifier property. To create a unique
>   identifier specific to your app, you can call the CFUUIDCreate
>   function to create a UUID, and write it to the defaults database using
>   the NSUserDefaults class.